# call angularjs state from html iframe

Tags: html, angularjs, iframe

I have angular application with login mechanism. User is logged in when there is 'auth token' stored in `$window.sessionStorage`. I have plain HTML iframe included on the page that shows logged in user data and 'logout' link. This link points to my angular state with controller. When I click 'logout' I can see that `$stateChangeStart` listener in app main controller is triggered:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if (UserFactory.isLoggedIn()) {
            //do something
        } else {
            //do something else
        }
    });
```

My problem is, that application does not recognize user as logged in, thus 'doing something else'.

my `UserFactory.isLoggedIn()` function is pretty simple:

```
isLoggedIn: function () {
    return 'token' in $window.sessionStorage;
}
```

My logout state is defined as:

```
.state('app.logout', {
    url: '/logout',
    templateUrl: 'auth/auth.login.tpl.html',
    controller: 'LogoutController',
})
```

and it works from within the angular app. In case I call 'logout' from iframe (non angular html) first thing triggered in my app is `$stateChangeStart` listener and it find no 'token' in `$window.sessionStorage`. Can somebody tell me why is that? What can be done so the application recognizes the user as logged in?

Comment: According to http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5/local-storage.html#sessionstorage-localstorage, "Popup windows opened from the same window can see session storage, and so can iframes inside the same window." So maybe the issue is not directly related to the use of serssionStorage within an iframe

Comment: `$window.sessionStorage` in iframe is not an issue. It's angular app that holds information if user is logged in, and it's this app `$stateChangeStart` listener that can't see 'token' in sessionStorage. Iframe points to angular app by `<a href="url_to_angular_state">logout</a>`

Comment: @OrGuz: You got me an idea, which fixed the problem. I had `$.sessionStorage.removeAll()` in my iframe javascript. This cleared the storage and that's why my angular app could not find anything in the storage.

Comment: Good catch my friend